# WSUS WID Database recovery

Tags: data-recovery, database, sql, wsus

My WSUS server, a Hyper-V VM running on a Window Server 2012 R2 Host, after a host power failure and later boot-up, showing error:

```
Application: 3414
Source: MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID
An error occurred during recovery, preventing the database 'SUSDB' (5:0) from restarting. Diagnose the recovery errors and fix them, or restore from a known good backup. If errors are not corrected or expected, contact Technical Support.

Application: 3313
Source: MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID
During redoing of a logged operation in database 'SUSDB', an error occurred at log record ID (1212707:3000:2). Typically, the specific failure is previously logged as an error in the Windows Event Log service. Restore the database from a full backup, or repair the database.

Application: 3456
Source: MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID
Could not redo log record (1212707:3000:2), for transaction ID (0:0), on page (1:635), allocation unit 281474979397632, database 'SUSDB' (database ID 5). Page: LSN = (1212704:2144:2), allocation unit = 281474979397632, type = 1. Log: OpCode = 4, context 18, PrevPageLSN: (1212705:11360:1). Restore from a backup of the database, or repair the database.
```

I believe WID SUSDB database got corrupted and unfortunately we don't have WSUS or Database backup. How do I repair the database since no SQL server management components is installed?

Appreciate your hep.

Answer (score -1):

The SUSDB seems to be corrupted and cannot come online making it not possible to connect to it using either SSMS or SQL CMD via the named pipes or TCP/IP. The SUSDB physical database files are located at `C:\Windows\WID\Data`. The files should be `SUSDB.mdf` and `SUSDB_log.ldf`. You can move the files to a another file location.

**NEXT STEPS:**
Since its a WSUS Server, you could re-install the WSUS role again to create new SUSDB and basically start from scratch.
Do you really want to repair it? A repair may cause data loss which could render the WSUS role in a unsupported state.
Do you still want to follow through, then you can try to attempt to attach the .***MDF*** file to another SQL Server instance and attempt to recreate the corrupt log file as mentioned in the error.
If that fails, then you might start looking into third party tools, a great one i use is [Stellar Phoenix SQL Database Repair](https://www.stellarinfo.com/sql-recovery.php) . It repairs databases using a powerful algorithm that can even retrieve deleted data. You can download a trial version via the link provided and test it out if you want to go this route.

HTH